# How to pass nested field parameters to a GraphQL query

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I'm trying to pass a field parameter from a variable. How can I do this when the field is nested? This doesn't seem to work.

```
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";

export const MY_QUERY = gql`
  query MY_QUERY($group: String!, $page: Int!) {
    myGroups(input: {group: $group, page: $page}) {
      
      groups {
        styleA(page: $page) {
          name
        }
      }
      
    }
  }
`;


const {loading: Loading, data : Data, error: Error } = useQuery(MY_QUERY, {
  variables: {
    group: group,
    page: page
  }
});
```

Comment: why not? error? how tested? query specs/input type? styleA resolver? ... whatever usable???

Comment: I'm using nuwave/lighthouse library for PHP and it seems it seems $page is not getting through (at the field parameter level). I get no value for that parameter on the server. Is this supposed to work though? I do get the value at the query level though.

Comment: I'm not using ... $args ?